# Is there a database of European surveillance radar installations?

Tags: radar, datasets, eu

Does anybody know a link to a database or appropriate webpage where I can find the locations of surveillance radar installations in Europe?

Comment: I somehow suspect this to be non public information.

Comment: @Federico You can find such data for US data on the web. Europe may be different, though.

Comment: Do you think about some particular kind of radar? Surveillance wording appears in primary and secondary "surveillance radar" (PSR / SSR). PSR is the true echo radar (some are military), SSR is a transponder interrogator. You probably need to look at each country individually, e.g. for France you have civil PSR and SSR on pages 19/20 of this non authoritative [document](https://www.anfr.fr/fileadmin/mediatheque/documents/etudes/Rapport%20perturbations%20fonctionnement%20radars%20fixes%20Aviation%20Civile%20et%20Defense%20par%20eoliennes.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the link. If available, i would be interested in the coordinates of both, PSR and SSR, civil as well as military. The purpose will be to use the data in simulation for radar coverage and frequency usage. For germany i found an official [document](https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/ebanzwww/contentloader/BAnz_AT_03_07_2017_B700.pdf?state.action=genericsearch_loadbundolpdf&state.filename=BAnz_AT_03_07_2017_B700.pdf&state.pubcode=14958377&&state.orig_filename=170611002010B001.pdf) here.

Answer (score 3):

Meanwhile i found an answer to my question. Location data of radar stations is for most countries provided in the AIP ENR chapter 1.6 "ATS Surveillance Services and Procedures". Some countries do not provide the coordinates of radar location, but only a coverage map. European AIP may be accessed through Eurocontrols EAD service.